# listener failed: socket() for [[-]:10050] failed: [13] Permission denied

Tags: sockets, permissions, listener, zabbix

When I run **zabbix_agentd -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf** as root, it would not start successfully. The **/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log** shows:

> "listener failed: socket() for [[-]:10050] failed: [13] Permission
>   denied"

No other information helpful I can find for trouble shooting, can some kind people help me?

> [root@njdc-mars-133 zabbix]# uname -r
>   3.4.94
>
> [root@njdc-mars-133 zabbix]# cat /etc/redhat-release  CentOS release
>   6.3 (Final)

Comment: Have you increased the log level?

Comment: I had set DebugLevel=5, only two lines more are recorded. "In zbx_load_modules(), End of zbx_load_modules():SUCCEED"

Comment: Agent likely drops permissions to another user, specified in the configuration file - unless you have a very old agent. This might be SELinux, blocking it. If SELinux is in the enforcing mode, does the problem go away if you temporarily set it to permissive?

Comment: we had disabled SELinux, but the kernel had been upgraded by other people. Is this can be the reason?